# share intent for image in android

Tags: android, share-intent

This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sharebutton:
            shareImage();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

     share.setType("image/*");
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/myImage.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
}
```

I am trying to share my image but it's not sharing. I am getting no error. Can anyone tell what's the problem?

Comment: if want another code then let me know..but please solve it..

Comment: Post your Androidmanifest file.

Comment: And the error from the LogCat

Answer (score 0):

```
String pathURL = "File Real Path"
Uri bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathURL));
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: this is my AndroidManifest.xml :

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: my image is parsed from json...so its not possible to get url of image-comeback4you

Comment: is it possible to get parsed image..?

Comment: I'm not getting your point parsed from json means? can you please paste json here.

Comment: where is the image url ?

Comment: where is the base url ? I suggest u one thing u need to download image then store the image then get the real path and follow above code.

Comment: public static final String HOST = "http://gpstracker.mpiricsoftware.com/etodonker/";                               public static final String GET_IMAGES_API = HOST + "offers.php";

Comment: can u give me example..? i am new to android